# You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders error showing in terminal when i installed nivo charts in my react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, nivo-react

**Error Message**

./node_modules/@react-spring/web/dist/esm/index.js 113:11

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (113:11)

The file was processed with these loaders:

*./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js

You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.

> ```
>   this.transforms = I;
> }
> _value = null;
> get() {
> return this._value || (this._value = this._get());
> ```

I did yarn add **@nivo/core @nivo/bar**

Please help me resolve this error.

Comment: Probably relevant issue: https://github.com/plouc/nivo/issues/2331

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to solve this issue:

1. option 1, Change update package.json
   update the **browserslist** property of package.json with

   ```
     browserslist: [
     ">0.2%",
     "not dead",
     "not op_mini all"
    ]
   ```
2. option 2, If you don't want to mess up with package.json then install a **different nivo version**.
   Nivo version above 0.80.0, seems to have a problem, so

   ```
   npm i @nivo/core@0.80.0, or the below version works well
   ```